# How to get the status of a particular stage in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

How do we get the status of the preceding stage(s) in a Jenkins pipeline. For example: My example pipeline is as under:

```
pipeline {
    agent
    {
        node {
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace "${env.JobPath}"
              }
    }

    stages 
    {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }

        stage ('set_env') {
            steps {
                // script to set environment.
            }
        }

        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                // script to build.
            }
        }

        stage ('Send_mail') {
            steps {
                // script to send mail.
            }
        }

        stage('End') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get the status of a particular stage in a pipeline. for ex: i want to take certain decisions based on whether the "Build" stage was a success or a failure.

Is there any environment variable which tracks the status of every stage, or there's a Jenkins REST API which can help me achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Via `currentBuild.result` you can set the status for the whole job. But if you only want to take decisions within your pipeline: how about using a normal groovy variable as a flag? If you set a variable within a global context you can use it across stages within the same build. Or maybe I'm not really getting the question right?

Comment: Thanks fishi for your suggestion. Kindly request you to elaborate on your logic with a sample code also. Thanks

Comment: I am looking for the same thing as I want to do some kind of report at the end of the build and I need to access all stages and to get the result for each of them. So far I was not able to find any code that does this.

Comment: did you find a solution? i am looking for a similar need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785704/jenkins-run-stage-repeatedly-and-parallely-until-another-stage-has-finished

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins declarative pipelines are opinionated syntax on top of the former jenkins pipeline approach. This means you can also regard a jenkins declarative pipeline as a groovy script with extra syntactic sugar. So you can freely use variables. As mentioned in my comment above, you can set the whole jobs status via `currentBuild.result`, but if you want to make decisions within the same job between stages: simply use groovy variables to indicate the state of the previous stage. Taking your example:

```
pipeline {

    def didSucceed = true

    agent
    {
        node {
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace "${env.JobPath}"
              }
    }

    stages 
    {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }

        stage ('set_env') {
            steps {
                // script to set environment.
                didSucceed = true // Here you indicate whether stuff actually worked..
            }
        }

        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                if (didSucceed) {
                    // script to build.
                } else {
                    // Procedure in case of previous error..
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Send_mail') {
            steps {
                // script to send mail.
            }
        }

        stage('End') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also stay in a more declarative way using the [when](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) statement in combination with a boolean variable.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't quite right. You need to at the very least put your evaluations of the variable in a `script{}` block. I'm also pretty sure that you need to declare your variable *outside* the pipeline.