# Jenkins run stage repeatedly and parallely until another stage has finished

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
stage("Run A and Run B") {
  parallel {
    stage('A') {

    }
    stage('B') {

    }
  }
}
```

Above setup will run stages A and B parallely. But i am looking for a way to run B repeatedly every 1 minutes, until stage A has finished. Could someone advice on on how do i tweak this?

Alternatively, if there is some way to get the status of stage A inside stage B , that would suffice my need.

For anyone curious, my use case is : I have some test running on stage A which will take few hours, and stage B has some code to zip the latest report from the test output and push it to a remote location

Comment: Please state the reason behind negative vote, so i can understand and improve myself. I had tried a lot to make the question as simple and direct as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a global variable.
The variable will be updated by the first parallel stage, which will use the variable to signal it has finished running, simultaneously the variable will be sampled by the second stage to verify if execution should proceed.
Something like:

```groovy
def running = true

pipeline {
    ...
    ...
    stage("Run A and Run B") {
    parallel  {
        stage('A') {
           // Run your stage A code
           // When finished update the running parameter
           running = false
        }
        stage('B') {
            while (running){
                // Run your stage B code as long as stage A is running
                sleep 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why i couldn't think of this. Simple and direct. thank you!